# PapaParse stream output to file

Tags: papaparse, node-streams

```js
const stream = require('stream');
const Transform = stream.Transform
const myTransform = new Transform({
  transform: (chunk, encoding, done)=>{
    console.log(`Received chunk for transform`)
    console.log(chunk)
    let result = chunk.join(",").toUpperCase()
    done(null, result)
  }
})
let papa = require('papaparse')
let file_stream = stream.Readable.from(Buffer.from("A,B,C\n1,2,3"));
let file_output_stream = fs.createWriteStream('final.csv');
file_stream.
  on("data", chunk => { console.log(`Read data`); console.log(chunk) }).
  pipe(papa.parse(papa.NODE_STREAM_INPUT, {})).
  on("data", row => {
    console.log(`Got row`)
    console.log(row)
  }).
  pipe(myTransform).
  pipe(file_output_stream)
```

The file seems to be read OK, but it doesn't seem my transform is being called at all.  papaparse is throwing an exception:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "chunk" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array. Received an instance of Array
```

I want final.csv to contain the original CSV, but in all capitals.  I need to do this streaming as the original file is quite large

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I went with a different CSV module: [how to use read and write stream of csv-parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54034911/how-to-use-read-and-write-stream-of-csv-parse)

papaparse may be a perfectly viable solution, but I wasn't able to figure out how to use it to do what I needed

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add `objectMode: true` to your `Transform` constructor.

This is because papaparse outputs an object, instead of a string or other data type normally expected by the transform stream.

like this:

```
const myTransform = new Transform({
  objectMode: true,
  transform: (chunk, encoding, done)=>{
    console.log(`Received chunk for transform`)
    console.log(chunk)
    let result = chunk.join(",").toUpperCase()
    done(null, result)
  }
})
```

I had a similar issue and found [someone had answered this here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71459663/13850437) which fixed it for me, so hopefully it does the same for you.